# Securing Xammp file on a windows oS

Tags: php, security

I want to install Xampp on my client machine for the organization to make use of the Application i build for them on a local network...
How can i secure the files in the htdocs in order to restrict third party from stealing/accessing the file of the App.
I will like to secure the files either using password or any other means and still make the Application files accessible by other systems.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's their machine? Then there's NOTHING you can do to prevent them from getting your code. If they have physical access to the box, then they have COMPLETE control over it.

Answer (score -1):

I would highly recommend against this, this is not what XAMPP was designed for.

I would set-up a virtual machine on their LAN and set-up a LAMP stack and host the application that way